# Exclude json files from index.android.bundle in react native

Tags: android, json, react-native, lottie, raw

In my react native app, I have many lottie files (json). I have added these json in res/raw folder, but these json files are getting included in the bundle Aldo. Now I want to exclude these json files from bundle and let the LottieView pick these json files from raw folder. I want this functionality so that my bundle get loaded much faster. I need anyone help in this. I am using metro config for bundle configuration.